# how to run the angular material migration script to webpack 5 project (ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration)

Tags: angular, webpack-5

how to run the angular material migration script to webpack 5 project (ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration)

I tried adding the script to packages script and called the migration script. but no luck

Added this to packages.json to sctipt :  "migrate-mdc": "ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration"

and run this command: npm run migrate-mdc

Comment: How do you know the migration failed? What versions of Angular and Angular Material did you use before the migration attempt?

Comment: "@angular/material": "16.2.11",
I am unable to run the script. Its a webpack project and I don't use angular.json in my project. Getting the -Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace(when running the command ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to use the Angular CLI without `angular.json`.

After having created an Angular project and then deleted the `angular.json` file:

```bash
$ ng generate component test
Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace.
```

You should also know that since the [release of Angular 17](https://blog.angular.io/introducing-angular-v17-4d7033312e4b), webpack has been replaced with esbuild and Vite.

Finally, there is no need to create a user-defined npm script to run the MDC migration since this migration is meant to execute only once per project.

Comment: Is there any possibilities to migrate to MDC in webpack project without angular.json

Comment: I don't see another way but to migrate manually since the migration tool is implemented as an Angular schematic which requires the Angular CLI. All changes are listed in [Migrating to MDC-based Angular Material Components](https://v16.material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration).